# How to create a Github release from a Jenkins-job (ideally with the list of commits since the last build/release)?

Tags: jenkins, github, gradle, release

I would like to have Github releases created automatically from the code of Jenkins-job. Ideally, I would like that these releases have also the generated release-notes in description that might be manually edited afterwards if necessary. Is it possible to write the Gradle-task or code (in Jenkinsfile) which make it work? 
We use Gradle as a build tool. Already have Git plugin installed on the Jenkins server. I guess that the Github API should be used (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release ), but as far as I see a release can be attached only to ONE commit (with its tag), while I would like to see eventually ALL commits that come along with this release (and since the previous one), not only the latest commit.

Comment: Github releases by definition point to a tag, which is a usual construct of releasing software. You might derive the changes (aka commits) by inspecting the Git history between the current tag and the previous version.

Comment: Would say the question is two-fold: a) generating the change log and b) creating a GitHub release via the API. Maybe you try a bit on both and then post a bit more specific question?

Comment: Maybe question is two-fold, but I can rephrase it shorter: I'd like to see the list of all commits between the current and the previous releases auto-generated (and attached to the current release), so is there any way to do this?

Comment: From your first reply I actually see only one approach so far: to retrieve from github all commits (since the last build in Jenkins) and to write it to release description.

Comment: So nothing related to GitHub then ;-) `git log <old-tag>..<new-tag>` would be the most naive way. Execute this in a jenkins pipeline's `sh` step and you got a bit of it. Figuring out what `<old-tag>` is is yet another challenge. Can certainly be calculated via groovy (decrement digit if it's not a 0).. sorry, I'm not aware of a straight-forward solution and would have to wind my head a bit more around it.

Comment: Probably there are some nice tools out there that generate a change log for you based on two git refs.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. git log is an interesting option. I found, however, that in Jenkins there's a "currentBuild.changeSets" object which contain all commits since the last build. So maybe that's a way to go..

Comment: Thought about this, but this requires that your previous build was really the previous release. If this is the case, sure.. go ahead!